# $match not finding objectID in mongoose 5.6+

Tags: match, aggregation, objectid

I have checked various posts already made on this topic before , but none of the suggestion worked for me. I have seen those suggestions will not work in mongoose 5.0. I am using mongoose 5.6. I tried with find(), which is working. but I need aggregation fm for extended usage. most of the suggestions were on converting record id mongoose.Types.ObjectId() which I used . but not worked me. pl help

here is my test code.

function totalActualSale  (recordId) {

```
Record.aggregate([
    {  
      $match : {
        '_id':mongoose.Types.ObjectId(recordId),
      }
    },
    {
        $unwind:  { "path": '$SalesList'}
    },
    { $group:
        {_id:
            {
                item:"$SalesList.item",
            },
            pqty: { $sum: '$SalesList.pqty' },
        }
    },
    ], function (err, purc) {

        console.log("\nStock:"+ JSON.stringify(purc));


});
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Actually the actual issue was just reverse. the 'recordId' passed to the function was the ObjectID of a record. so, when comparing we should convert that into string. recordId.toString().  So the solution is 

function totalActualSale (recordId) {

Record.aggregate([
    {  
      $match : {
        '_id':recordId.toString(),
      }
    },
    {
        $unwind:  { "path": '$SalesList'}
    },
    { $group:
        {_id:
            {
                item:"$SalesList.item",
            },
            pqty: { $sum: '$SalesList.pqty' },
        }
    },
    ], function (err, purc) {

        console.log("\nStock:"+ JSON.stringify(purc));


});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
function totalActualSale (recordId) {

Record.aggregate([
    {  
      $match : {
        '_id':new mongoose.mongo.ObjectId(recordId),
      }
    },
    {
        $unwind:  { "path": '$SalesList'}
    },
    { $group:
        {_id:
            {
                item:"$SalesList.item",
            },
            pqty: { $sum: '$SalesList.pqty' },
        }
    },
    ], function (err, purc) {

        console.log("\nStock:"+ JSON.stringify(purc));


});
}
```

Comment: I presume your suggestion is to use " new mongoose.mongo.ObjectId " instead of "mongoose.Types.ObjectId". It did not work for me.

Comment: No. It did not return any data